# Using recursive xsl files

Tags: java, xml, xslt, xsd

I have been developing two xsl (say for example A and B) files. *A.xsl* is dependent on *B.xsl*. And in *B.xsl* file, I was hard-coding some elements and after that it should depend on *A.xsl*. Is there anyway to recursively check these two xsl files.

Is there anyway to do this. Or if no ? Please say your answer no if not applicable.

Here i was intersted in transforming xml files, where most of the xml elements are common, then i thought to develop an xsl file that have elements in common to one template and call it from other xsl file by using include. However, i was stucked at a point where an element have necessary hard coding and then shall use the generic xsl again. Below is the example: This example is generic, i dont want to hardcode the generic xsl file eachtime when i use for many other xsls that to develop.

This is a sample for input xml.

```
<element>
   <subelement></subelement>
</element>
```

This is a sample for output xml.

```
<element>
   <element2></element2>
   <subelement></subelement2>
</element>
```

This is A.xsl

```
<xsl:inculde href="B.xsl">
<xsl:call-template name="ele"/>
```

This is B.xsl

```
<xsl:template name="ele">
<xsl:copy-of select="element"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean. Do you want to call a A.xsl, which includes a B.xsl, wihch includes A.xsl itsef? I think this link may help: http://www.apply-templates.com/blog/xsl-include-vs-import

Comment: Reeks like you need a C.xsl. But you could state your problem somewhat more in detail.

Comment: What does "check these two xsl files" mean? And when you say "refer the other xsl file in between" ... in between what and what?

Answer (score 1):

It's not completely clear what you mean by A.xsl and B.xsl being *dependent* on each other, but it sounds as if you are probably looking for a way to maintain two or more stylesheets for two transformation tasks that have a lot of behavior in common but differ in some ways.

For concreteness, I'm going to assume that you have two transformations in mind, which I'll call Red and Green (to avoid confusing them with your A and B, which may or may not be exactly the same thing), which have the property that:

- Many elements (say, elements C1, C2, ... Cn) are handled just the same way in the two transforms.
- Some elements (D1, D2, ... Dn) are handled differently.
- In addition, there may be elements R1, R2, ... Rn, which are seen only in the input to the Red transform, and G1, G2, ... Gn, which are seen only in the input to the Green transform.

There are several ways to structure the Red and Green transforms in XSLT.  Two of the easiest to explain are these.

(1) Make three stylesheets:  C.xsl (for the common elements), R.xsl (for the Red transformation of the R elements and D elements), G.xsl (for the Green transformation of the G elements and D elements).  R.xsl and G.xsl each include or import C.xsl, so the code for common elements with a single handling method is written and maintained in just one place.

(2) Make two stylesheets.  Red.xsl defines the complete Red transformation; it covers the common elements C1, C2, etc., the elements with different handling (D1, D2, etc.), and the elements unique to the Red transform (R1, R2, etc.).  It imports nothing.

Green.xsl imports Red.xsl and includes templates for the D and G elements.  Because it has no templates for the C elements, the C elements will be handled the same way in the Green transformation as in the Red transformation.  Because Green.xsl is the main stylesheet for the Green transformation, the Green.xsl templates for D elements will have higher priority than the Red.xsl templates for the same elements.  The templates for R elements will also be imported, but since no R elements occur in the input, they will match nothing and do no harm.

What you need to read up on in any good reference book (or the XSLT spec, which is perfectly readable technical prose) are the `xsl:import` and `xsl:include` elements, the `priority` attribute on `xsl:template`, and the concept of *import precedence*.